# Deploy Firebase Function but choosing Python instead of TS

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Just installed Firebase Functions to my project using `firebase init functions` and selected Python as my language instead of TS. When I try to deploy the test function I'm getting the error

```bash
Error: Could not detect language for functions at /home/foo/bar/myproject/functions
```

The function is just the default one:

```py
# Welcome to Cloud Functions for Firebase for Python!
# To get started, simply uncomment the below code or create your own.
# Deploy with `firebase deploy`

from firebase_functions import https_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app

initialize_app()


@https_fn.on_request()
def on_request_example(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")
```

I already have my env set up using poetry and have installed requirements.txt. Is there something I'm missing when choosing python instead of TS?

#### Update 1

I removed my functions/ folder and recreated my poetry env because hey might get lucky. After manually installing the dependencies with `cat functions/requirements.txt | xargs poetry add` then `firebase deploy --only fuctions` I'm faced with:

```bash
Failed to find location of Firebase Functions SDK: Missing virtual environment at venv directory.
```

It's important to note here that I don't have a venv folder since I'm using poetry and all my envs are in a centralized location. I may be wrong but it looks like Firebase doesn't want to use my poetry env. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a permanent solution but since the firebase cli is just too stubborn to realize an env was already running I went ahead and created a sym link of the `activate` file it needs to my actual env.

```bash
# ~/myproject/functions/venv/bin
ln -s /path-to-env/bin/activate
```

Hopefully this can be fixed by being able to identify the location of the activate file in the cli. Or if there is one and I missed it please let me know.

Meanwhile, I'm just happy I can write my functions in python now.